# I have written test class for this trigger where this is showing code coverage 76%?

Tags: trigger, unit-test

Trigger:

```
trigger updateacccounts on Contact (after insert,after delete,after undelete) {
    set<id> plist=new set<id>();
    list<account> acclist=new list<account>();
    if(trigger.isinsert || trigger.isundelete){
        for(contact c:trigger.new)
        {
            plist.add(c.accountid);
        }
    }
    if(trigger.isdelete){
        for(contact c1:trigger.old)
        {
            plist.add(c1.accountid);
        }
    }
    for(account acc:[select id,name,No_of_Contacts__c,(select id,name from contacts) from account where id=:plist])
    {
        acc.No_of_Contacts__c=acc.contacts.size();
        acclist.add(acc);
    }
    try{
        update acclist;
    }
    catch(exception e)
    {
        system.debug('running acclist');
    }
}
```

Test Class:

```
@istest
public class updateacccounts_Tc{
    static testmethod void updateacccounts_Tc()
    {
        account acc=new account(name='xxxx',No_of_Contacts__c=1233);
        insert acc;
        contact c=new contact(lastname='xxxx');
        insert c;
        contact c1=[select id,lastname from contact where id=:c.id];
        delete c1;
    }
}
```

Image of Code Coverage:
[image]

Comment: so wats ur question ? increasing code coverage to 100% ??

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code you will get 94% coverage for your snippet

```
@istest
public class updateacccounts_Tc{
static testmethod void updateacccounts_Tc()
{
account acc=new account(name='xxxx',No_of_Contacts__c=1233);
insert acc;
string a=acc.id;
contact c=new contact(lastname='YYYY',AccountId=a);
insert c;
contact c1=[select id,lastname from contact where id=:c.id];
delete c1;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you contact created in test data doesnot have any relation ship with account but the uncovered code part where you are qureying the contact from account and you might receive no records and it is not going into for loop so.
change your creation of contact as forllows.

```
Contact cnt = new Contact(LastName='xxxxxx', AccountId='acc.Id');
Insert cnt;
```

Thanx

Comment: got 94% still it is there at try catch block

Comment: if there is no exception it will not go into the catch block. you may need to write another test method which may throw an exception. and 94 % is more enough. Instead of try catch you can do an if (!accList.isEmpty()){ update accList;}

Answer (score 0):

The `Contact` record in your test should be linked to the `Account` in your test so that the SOQL query in your test returns some data. See below for how to link them up.

```
    Account acc=new Account(name='xxxx', No_of_Contacts__c=1233);
    insert acc;
    Contact c=new Contact(lastname='xxxx', AccountId = acc.Id);
    insert c;
```

You should also be doing an assert in your test to make sure that `No_of_Contacts__c` is being set correctly, something like what is shown below will work

```
    System.assertEquals(1, [select No_of_Contacts__c 
                            from Account where Id =:acc.Id].No_of_Contacts__c);
    delete c;
    System.assertEquals(0, [select No_of_Contacts__c 
                            from Account where Id =:acc.Id].No_of_Contacts__c);
```

As for getting the `catch` block in the `try catch` covered, I would recommend removing the `try catch` completely. If an error happens in your code you are stopping it from being thrown and it will go unnoticed. If there is no reason to do this then remove the `try catch`. At the moment your trigger could be throwing an error and your test would still pass.

You are also missing a scenario in your logic. The `Account` lookup field on `Contact` can be changed after the `Contact` is created. To cover this scenario you would need to trigger on a `Contact` record being updated, where the `Account` field is changed. You would need to requery the `No_of_Contacts__c` field for the old `Account` and the new `Account` in this scenario.